# No results come back when adding temptable and querying it in SQLSRV

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, sqlsrv

I am trying to create a temptable and do some calculations that populates the temptable and finally get the results from the created temp table. But so far I have been unsuccessful. My query is a little bit more involved but here is the thing that I am trying to do. This code assumes we have database connection set up with codeigniter.

```
-- This generate no results i.e. Array ()
$sql = "CREATE TABLE #output(name varchar NULL, id int NULL);
            insert into #output (name,id) VALUES('sam',5) 
            SELECT * FROM #output";
$res = $this->db->query($sql);

--Also tried this and returns nothing
$queryList = [
    'sql1' => "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#output', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #output;",
    'sql2' => "CREATE TABLE #output(name varchar NULL, id int NULL);",
    'sql3' => "insert into #output (name,id) VALUES('sam',5)",
    'sql4' => "SELECT * FROM #output"
        ];
$result = array();
        foreach($queryList as $key => $value){
            $result[$key] = $this->db->query($value, FALSE, TRUE); 
        }
```

These two were written to use codeigniter db drivers. None of the above queires even resulted in #output temptable in the tempdb of the database.

I also tried using `sqlsrv_query` directly, this one at least created the #output temptable but did not give me any results back.

```
-- Created the #output temptable but didn't give me back the data inserted
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
            if( $conn ) {
                 echo "Connection established.<br />";
                 $sql = "CREATE TABLE #output(name varchar NULL, id int NULL);
            insert into #output (name,id) VALUES('sam',5) 
            SELECT * FROM #output
            --DROP TABLE #output";
            $stm = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql,[]);
            while( $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $stm )) {
                echo $obj->name . '<br />';
                //print_r($obj);
          }
```

I have been trying a lot of scenarios but couldn't figure out what is wrong with my code. Oh BTW I also tried `codeigniter` `trans_start()` and end and added every query as a separate query but that didn't work out either. I couldn't think or search anything else and so here is my request for a help.

Here is my environment:

- SQLSRV 5.3
- SQL server 2012
- ODBC Driver 17
- CodeIgniter 3.1.9
- PHP 7.0.31

Comment: You may try to execute CREATE, INSERT and SELECT statements separately with sqlsrv_query() function.

Comment: And check for errors after sqlsrv_query() with something like this: if ($stm === false) {print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true); exit;}. It will be useful to see if there are some error messages. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Zhorov for the hint. I would try and see what is the issue.

Comment: I couldn't separate all the query parts because next time there won't be any temptable to insert into. But I added the sqlsrv_erros and no errors are coming back. I am even getting Resource ID, but when trying sqlsrv_fetch_object($stm) nothing comes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

You need to fix some issues:

- define `varchar` columns with this format: `varchar [(n|max)]`. When `n` is not specified, the default length is 1 and when you try to INSERT value 'sam', a warning will be generated.
- put `SET NOCOUNT ON;` as first statement. If you miss that part, your statement will return more than one resultset, so you must make resultsets available by using `sqlsrv_next_result()`.

**Working example:**

```
<?php
$server   = 'server\instance,port';
$database = 'database';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$cinfo = array(
    "Database" => $database,
    "UID" => $username,
    "PWD" => $password
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if ($conn === false) {
    echo print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

# Statement
$sql = "
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    CREATE TABLE #output(name varchar(50) NULL, id int NULL);
    INSERT INTO #output (name, id) VALUES ('sam', 5);
    SELECT * FROM #output;
";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if ($stmt === false) {
    echo print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

# Results
while ($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object($stmt)) {
   echo 'Name: '.$obj->name.'</br>';
   echo 'ID: '.$obj->id.'</br>';
}

# End
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

**Notes:**

I'm not so familiar with CodeIgniter, but I think that this is your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Zhorov. SET NOCOUNT ON; resolved the issue. I read somewhere we need it for stored procedures but didn't know we need it for these kind of multi step queries.